# How To find the location of any treeviewitem in silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Hi I am new in silverlight 3.
I want to find the location of any treeview Item .
Although I applied this code

```
GeneralTransform gt = ProjectTree.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual as UIElement);
Point offset = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

double controlTop = offset.Y;
double controlLeft = offset.X;
```

Here Project tree is the root element of the treeview.
This code is working 
But when I applied this for any child TreeViewelement of  Treeview 
then an exception occurs "Value does not fall within the expected range."
How to find the location of this child treeview element object

Comment: Could you show us code that isn't working?